# Should I avoid blocking code in netty-grpc?

Tags: java, grpc, netty, grpc-java

The most popular option is running `grpc` server on `netty`, in my understanding `netty` use a worker event loop group which call handlers in the pipeline, so basically my rpc is one of these handlers in the pipeline. `Netty` doesn’t like long blocking code, so in my rpc should I avoid blocking code, or could write good-old blocking servers?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are talking about receiving messages from the server. For send, the message is queued up once you send until it is flushed, you can not block netty at sending.

For message you received from wire, the netty transport immediately handover to call executor. Processing of your RPC will jump and be scheduled on the call executor. So the netty server does not block even when you write blocking code.
Feel free to write blocking code when using grpc-java. It has nothing to do with blocking netty.

Comment: So there is another pool in worker group? That’s why we could block?

Comment: There is actually another layer of abstraction. The call is handled in [executor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#executor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) and [callexecutor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#callExecutor(io.grpc.ServerCallExecutorSupplier)), there are configurable, but by default they are normal java cache executor. Handling application rpc are on those configurable executor not directly on the eventloop. The tasks run on the worker group hands over to these executors.

Comment: But why then use Netty? I thought it’s highperform becausr use loop but if it’s single responsibility is resolving future from executor, then we still have a lot of threads and performance should be same as blocking servers(like jetty)